# MYSQL output doesn't make sense

Tags: mysql

Input:
Person table:

```
+----+---------+
| id | email   |
+----+---------+
| 1  | a@b.com |
| 2  | c@d.com |
| 3  | a@b.com |
+----+---------+
```

My query is

```
SELECT one.email AS Email
FROM Person AS one, Person AS two
```

and the output is

```
| Email   |
| ------- |
| a@b.com |
| c@d.com |
| a@b.com |
| a@b.com |
| c@d.com |
| a@b.com |
| a@b.com |
| c@d.com |
| a@b.com |
```

I am very new to MYSQL and this output does not make sense to me. I created two aliases for a single table as one and two but "one.email" returns the same table not once or twice but **thrice**. I am quite baffled by this behavior. Please explain how does the output contains three copies of the table.

Comment: With no `JOIN` condition you are doing a cartesian join, so each row in `one` will join each row in `two`. 3 x 3 = 9 results.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, does not listing JOIN condition automatically result in CROSS JOIN?

Comment: As @Valuator says. Put all columns in the query (`SELECT one.id, one.email, two.id, two.email`) to see how it works. Add different aliases to the expressions to make clear which value comes from each table (`SELECT one.id AS id1, one.email as email1, two.id AS id2, two.email AS email2 FROM Person AS one, Person AS two
`).

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/join.html says:

> `INNER JOIN` and `,` (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table).

If you are just now learning SQL, you should get into the habit of using the `JOIN` syntax. The old syntax that uses a comma for join was obsolete in 1992.